# Rest framework: TypeError: 'exceptions.KeyError' object is not callable on invalid token

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using rest framework's Token authentication for my api. Recently I've found an issue that, If the Token provided in the request is invalid, instead of returning `Invalid Token` response, django throws `TypeError at /api/users/: 'exceptions.KeyError' object is not callable`.

I checked on the trace, and found this:
In django/db/models/query.py(Django version=1.7) file line no 357, inside raise `DoesNotExists` exception call, the actual exception `TypeError` raised by `self.model._meta.object_name`.

```
    if num == 1:
        return clone._result_cache[0]
    if not num:
        raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
            "%s matching query does not exist." %
            self.model._meta.object_name)
```

Does anybody knows why model's object_name became `exception.KeyError` rather than `Token`?

Answer (score 0):

Bizarrely, I got this when I had this line in my code:

```
except KeyError, models.MyModel.DoesNotExist:
```

where the comma was interpreted as "as", redefining models.MyModel.DoesNotExist as a KeyError and causing "exception.KeyError is not callable" when creating one.

What I meant to do was:

```
except (KeyError, models.MyModel.DoesNotExist):
```